# Piping To Grep Is Giving Too Many Results

Tags: linux, unix, grep, linux-mint

I'm trying to check whether a particular service is running via a Linux terminal, and the following command doesn't seem to be filtering the results as expected.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

```
service --status-all | grep subversion
```

This produces several lines of output, including, for example,

```
 [ ? ] Networking
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, since the string "subversion" is not contained within the above line...

Comment: What about `service subversion status; ret=$?; echo $ret`?

Comment: Thanks, that will definitely work, but I'm still wondering why grep is producing extra results...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
service --status-all |& grep subversion
```

Because the services without a status (`[ ? ]`) are sent to stderr, which is not pipelined to grep (and then it is printed on your terminal regardless).

`|&` sends stderr to stdout so grep is able to filter it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this and redirect [stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) (2) to stdout (1):

```
service --status-all 2>&1 | grep subversion
```